# Why has this question so many downvotes?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, down-votes

I just found a question

[Example of map from commutative ring to another commutative that preserves multiplicative identity and addition but NOT multiplication.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245813/example-of-map-from-commutative-ring-to-another-commutative-that-preserves-multi?rq=1)

that has 4 downvotes and is closed as off-topic, though everything seems to be fine. There are no comments explaining what is going on (even though the user is/was new to the community). So what makes this question so "rejected"?

Comment: I guess the OP's not always constructive attitude displayed in [some edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2245813/revisions) contributed to it. There was a comment explaining what's going on there, but that was later deleted by the commenter.

Comment: BTW if you look at the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2245813/revisions) or [the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2245813/timeline) of the post, you can see also that at the time the question was closed it [looked like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2245813/1).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks, looking at the revision history did not not cross my mind, but anyway, the question probably should not be (have been) closed any longer, so it is a success anyway